# What's the difference between require("node:<something>") and require("<something>")?

Tags: node.js

I've always used `require("<something>")` such as `require("http")`, but recently I've seen in a Node.Js tutorial on YouTube that the guy in the videos initially started with `require("<something>")` only to see in his later videos that he uses `require("node:<something>")` instead.

I've looked through the Node.JS documentation every now and then for some other bits on information and either Node.Js does not use `require("node:<something>")` everywhere, or I have been extremely oblivious to that `node:`.

I've ran a few Google searches on `node:` and tried to look on Node.Js' documentation about this specific thing, but didn't really find much.

From my tests, I could not find a difference between the two and I do tend to believe that there isn't any, but thought I'd ask here just to be safe.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#node-imports

Comment: Ok, now this is annoying. I swear I have searched on google and on stackoverflow even for `node:` and nothing that was returned was relevant to me. Yes, what you've posted answers my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Node.js, the **require()** function is used to load modules and files. The syntax require("something") is used to load a module or file named "something" from the local file system or from the installed node_modules directory.

On the other hand, **require("node:something")** is used to load a module that is part of the Node.js core modules. This syntax allows you to explicitly specify that you want to load a module from the Node.js built-in modules, rather than from the local file system or an installed package.

The use of node: prefix is helpful in cases where there might be a module with the same name in both the Node.js core modules and the local file system or installed packages. By specifying node:something, you ensure the module is loaded from the Node.js core modules.

It's worth noting that using require("node:something") is typically not necessary for most common use cases, as the core modules are automatically resolved without explicitly specifying the node: prefix. The prefix is primarily used to disambiguate module names in rare cases where conflicts may arise.

Hope this makes things clear.